How to apply scanned value into lenght of the Array in go language?
I want to add the scanned values into length of array, but my code has an error.
We can't do that like other programming languages.
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var number_of_student int

    fmt.Print("Enter the number of Student: ")
    fmt.Scan(&number_of_student)

    var Student_marks [number_of_student]int

    for i := 0; i <= number_of_student-1; i++ {
        fmt.Print("Enter the ", i+1, " student mark")
        fmt.Scan(&Student_marks[i])
    }
}

I expect that i can add scanned values into length of array. In terminal there is an error; it says "invalid array length number_of_student".

For your usecase, you should use a slice instead of an array, this would work:
var studentCount int

fmt.Print("Enter the number of Student: ")
fmt.Scan(&studentCount)

studentMarks := make([]int, studentCount)

for i := 0; i < len(studentMarks); i++ {
    fmt.Print("Enter the ", i+1, " student mark: ")
    fmt.Scan(&studentMarks[i])
}


In Go, the length of an array (which is static array) must be a constant expression known at compile time.
If you want to use dynamic array - use slices:
https://go.dev/tour/moretypes/7

We can use append function and do it another way.we need to make another variable to add this data to array
import "fmt"

func main() {

var number_of_student int

var marks int //another variable

fmt.Print("Enter the number of Student: ") fmt.Scan(&number_of_student)

var Student_marks[] int //we need to keep array without adding its length

for i:=0;i<=number_of_student-1;i++{

fmt.Print("Enter the ",i+1," student mark") 

fmt.Scan(&marks)

Student_marks=append(student_marks,marks)//use append function

}
}
